# Asp code when moved - parse error

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to combine 2 asp pages into one but when I move the following code from one working page page and place it at the bottom of my other working page I get a parse error on this line

`<asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server" Width="80%" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Calibri" BackColor="White" GroupingText="Password Retrieval">
            <table style="width: 75%; height: 28%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">`

Does anyone have any ideas.

Thanks
Ross

Comment: Is that all the code? where do you close the panel?

Comment: No there is more code below, and as mentioned it was working when the code was on a page on its own but now its not and the parse error is on this line

Comment: are you trying to use the asp panel on a classic asp page?  .asp file extension?  those are asp.net tags.  will not work on asp.  Just curious since your question is listed as both asp.net / asp classic question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that bit of code as far as I can see - what exact error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you have moved **only** this portion of code, then you will indeed get an error.

You need a close tag for your `<asp:Panel>` to prevent an ASP.NET error.

You also need a close tag for your `table` element to prevent HTML validation errors.

---

However, if this is just a snippet, and you do in fact have a close tag, then check that no other control on the page has a `Panel1` ID. IDs must be unique per web form.